# CakePHP Not Loading Behaviors of Related Models on Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm programming a plugin for a CakePHP app that has the following Models:

Preregistry Model

```
App::uses('PreinscriptionAppModel', 'Preinscription.Model');

class Preregistry extends PreinscriptionAppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Relative'
    );

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Date' => array(
            'birthday' => array(
               'format' => '%d/%m/%Y'
            ),
            'registry_date' => array(
                'format' => '%d/%m/%Y'
            )
        )
   );
}
```

Relative Model

```
App::uses('PreinscriptionAppModel', 'Preinscription.Model');

class Relative extends PreinscriptionAppModel {
    public $name = 'Relative';

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Date' => array(
            'birthday' => array(
                'format' => '%d/%m/%Y'
            )
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Preregistry'
    );
}
```

The Relevant part of the Controller is:

```
<?php

App::uses('PreinscriptionAppController', 'Preinscription.Controller');

class PreregistriesController extends PreinscriptionAppController {
    public function add() {
        $preregistryDateConfig = $this->Preregistry->getDateConfig();
        $relativeDateConfig = $this->Preregistry->Relative->getDateConfig();
    }
}
```

The problem i have is when calling `$this->Preregistry->Relative->getDateConfig();` the Date Behavior is not loaded on the `Relative` model so it throws a MySQL error because the model doesn't have a `getDateConfig()` method.

When i check if the Behavior is loaded with `$this->Preregistry->Relative->Behaviors->loaded('Date');` i get FALSE back.

For some reason the Behavior is only loaded in the `Preregistry` model but not on the `Relative` model. I also have tried to load the Behavior on the fly to no success.

If someone could tell me a workaround for this problem i will be very glad.

If you need more code or anything feel free to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `debug($this->Preregistry->Relative)` will show that `Relative` is an instance of `AppModel`.

This is because you are missing the proper plugin name in your associations, it should be:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Preinscription.Relative'
);
```

and

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Preinscription.Preregistry'
);
```

otherwise CakePHP won't grab the models from the plugin, but create an instance of `AppModel` for the associations instead (in case there are no `Relative` respective `Preregistry` in any of the configured model locations), which is then of course missing your `Date` behavior.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-models**